# Programmatically delete the earlies data files from the data folder

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I am trying to delete the earlies (oldest) datasets and keep only 3 of them (the earliest) For example, the viewers by app file, the first 3 datasets are the earlies, as you can see the date attached and the time. The rest 3 of them, are older, and do not want to keep them, good for deletion. The same with log metrics files; the first 3 are the earliest and want to keep them, but the last 3 are the oldest and want to delete them.

Is there a way to programmatically delete, in R, the files I do not need? It would be nice to embed the tidyverse library with this solution.

[image]

Here are the code I have written to actually created these data, just so that you are aware of how I have created these.

```
readr::write_csv(log_metrics,
                     paste0(
                       "data/generated_metrics/log_metrics",
                       format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d%H%M"),
                       ".csv"
                     ))
```

Comment: Can you paste the filenames as text not image? `list.file(pattern = "^viewers")`

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

directory <- "data/generated_metrics" # Files' path

list.files(directory, pattern = "log_metrics", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  file.info() %>%
  arrange(ctime) %>% # Sort files by creation time  
  rownames() %>% 
  .[-c(1:3)] %>%
  file.remove()
```

Comment: I get this error when running your code - Error in sort(ctime, index.return = TRUE)$ix : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Yes, I will work this latter

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more tidyverse way of doing what you are after than Julien's (imho).

```
library(fs)
library(tidyverse)

your_path %>%
  # listing all files with the pattern "log_metrics"
  list.files(pattern = "log_metrics", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  # getting the info about the files
  fs::file_info() %>%
  # removing the three most recent files from the data.frame
  slice_min(order_by = birth_time, n = -3) %>%
  # taking only the path from the data.frame
  pull(path) %>%
  # removing the files
  file.remove()
```

Comment: I need to keep only the most recent 3 files the rest, no matter how many should be deleted. I do not ge the code working

Comment: This is what the code is supposed to do. It first lists all files, than removes the 3 most recent, and then deletes the rest.

Comment: well, I have done it and doesn't do the trick!